# Camera control box plugged into the router, any idea how I can find its IP?

Tags: router, ip-address, lookup

In the past I've used it but recently I got a new router. I plugged the camera control box in, and it has an internal webserver to configure it. However I just have no idea what its IP address is. I don't know the model of it, and I can't find any manuals or instructions. It doesn't show up in the DHCP client list on my router, and I have tried pinging/http on the obvious IPs it could be, 192.168.1.1 etc.

I guess since it's just sitting there not doing anything that that is the reason it hasn't shown up on my router's DHCP list. Does anyone have any idea how I can figure out what the IP of it is?

Answer (score 0):

If the camera uses mDNS/IPv4LL then you can use a mDNS discovery client such as `avahi-discover` to see what mDNS devices are available on the local network.

Answer (score 0):

my usual method for doing this:

plug it directly into a compute with a crossover cable (or into a spare switch), set the pc to 192.168.1.178 (or something unlikely to be the camera) and run `nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24` will return all live addresses. Should be two, your machine and the camera's.

`ping 255.255.255.255` should also work.